# ShowDialog Form property is empty

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have two of the simplest forms, with a couple of Buttons and a TextBox. I click to open the second form (frmModal) using ShowDialog(), type some text into txtGreeting and press the Yes button. What should happen is that a MessageBox appears confirming the text that was entered into txtGreeting, but it is empty.

I understand that the Form's properties should be accessible until the form goes out of scope, but they disappear straight-away. I can't even read dialog.txtGreeting.Text.

Am I missing anything obvious please?

```
 Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub btnModal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnModal.Click
        Dim dialog As frmModal

        dialog = New frmModal()
        Dim result As DialogResult = frmModal.ShowDialog(Me)
        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            MessageBox.Show(dialog.Greeting)
        End If
        'dialog.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class frmModal
        Public Property Greeting As String
            Get
                Return txtGreeting.Text
            End Get
            Set(value As String)

        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub btnYes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnYes.Click
        MessageBox.Show(Greeting)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Yes button has it's DialogResult property set to Yes.

I've tried moving the dialog-declaration out of the click-event, using an (unnecessary) Dispose(), deliberately assigning the Greeting property in the Yes-click event..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're effectively instantiating the form twice.  By showing frmModal with ShowDialog and then asking for the Greeting value on the instance you created, named 'dialog'.

This should fix it.

```
   Private Sub ModalTestButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ModalTestButton.Click
        Dim dialog As frmModal

        dialog = New frmModal()
        Dim result As DialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog(Me)
        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            MessageBox.Show(dialog.Greeting)
        End If

    End Sub
```